# How to use VXG android sdk?

Tags: android, sdk, android-mediaplayer

Please help how to use **VXG Android SDK** And to resolve a fetal error I have faced while using it .I have used following code  to configure Media player and button click listener to  play.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements MediaPlayer.MediaPlayerCallback{
    public String videoUrl="http://130.185.144.63:8000/live/pakistan/pakistan/6.ts";        
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;   
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;    
    public Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer=(MediaPlayer) findViewById(R.id.player); 
        mediaPlayer.getSurfaceView().setZOrderOnTop(true);   
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    if(mediaPlayer!=null){   
                        mediaPlayer.getConfig().setConnectionUrl(videoUrl);
                        //this is place for the video configuration
                        MediaPlayerConfig mediaPlayerConfig=new MediaPlayerConfig();
                        mediaPlayerConfig.setConnectionUrl(videoUrl);
                        mediaPlayerConfig.setNumberOfCPUCores(0);
                        mediaPlayerConfig.setRendererType(1);
                        mediaPlayerConfig.setDecodingType(1);
                        mediaPlayerConfig.setSynchroEnable(1);
                        mediaPlayerConfig.setConnectionNetworkProtocol(-1);
                        mediaPlayer.Open(mediaPlayerConfig,MainActivity.this);
                        //end of the video place for the configuration
                    }//end of the conditional check
                    PrintToast("Working");
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    PrintToast("Exception of type "+ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }//end of the on create activity




    //this is for the printing the toast
    public void PrintToast(String Line){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Line,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int Status(int i) {
        if(i==MediaPlayer.PlayerNotifyCodes.PLP_PLAY_SUCCESSFUL.ordinal()){
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int OnReceiveData(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, int i, long l) {
        return 0;
    }
    //end of the printing the toast
}
```

And When Button is clicked it leads to the following fetal error:

```
12-17 20:29:51.255 19811-19984/mashhood.meshsoft.com.vxgfullwork E/art: No implementation found for long veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayer.nativePlayerInit(long[], veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayer) (tried Java_veg_mediaplayer_sdk_MediaPlayer_nativePlayerInit and Java_veg_mediaplayer_sdk_MediaPlayer_nativePlayerInit___3JLveg_mediaplayer_sdk_MediaPlayer_2)
12-17 20:29:51.256 19811-19984/mashhood.meshsoft.com.vxgfullwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MediaPlayerThread
                                                                                   Process: mashhood.meshsoft.com.vxgfullwork, PID: 19811
                                                                                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayer.nativePlayerInit(long[], veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayer) (tried Java_veg_mediaplayer_sdk_MediaPlayer_nativePlayerInit and Java_veg_mediaplayer_sdk_MediaPlayer_nativePlayerInit___3JLveg_mediaplayer_sdk_MediaPlayer_2)
                                                                                       at veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayer.nativePlayerInit(Native Method)
                                                                                       at veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayerWorker.run(MediaPlayer.java:4051)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

So Please guide how to use it effectively

Answer (score 1):

Following steps resolved the same issue in my project. Hope it will fix others too.

1. Downloaded latest android VXG project from GitHub.
2. Goto VXG.MediaPlayer.Android/libs and copy arm64-v8a, x86, armeabi-v7a folders, and mediaplayersdk.jar file
3. Goto, you project app/src/main and create a folder with name jniLibs
4. Past all the copied folders and file.
5. Goto, VXG.MediaPlayer.Android⁩/src⁩/AndroidStudio⁩/RTSP_Player⁩/app⁩/src⁩/main⁩/libs⁩ and copy org.apache.http.legacy.jar
6. In your project go to app/src/main/libs and then past org.apache.http.legacy.jar file. create a libs folder if not available.
7. Finally add compile files('libs/mediaplayersdk.jar'), compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar') in app/build.gradle.
8. Run your application.

Sourec: https://www.dropbox.com/s/krsr6f5pbr3hvui/20160502_Release_AndroidStudioProjects_MediaPlayerSDKTest.pdf?dl=0